# How to validate values in a list of object?

Tags: c#, list, linq-to-objects

I have a `List<ObjectA>` populated.
Class ObjectA has two properties -`string property1` `bool? property2`

[1]I need to loop through the entire list to check if property1 contains a particular string say 'xyz'.

[2] I need to check if value of property2 is true(which i believe i can figure out after getting to know how to handle [1])

thanks
Adarsh

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With `List<T>` you can also use its method [`TrueForAll`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kdxe4x4w%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
bool valid = list.TrueForAll(a => a.property1.Contains("xyz") && a.property2);
```

This will work on any version of .NET >= 2.0. You also can use LINQ as @Hassan suggested:

```
bool valid = list.All(a => a.property1.Contains("xyz") && a.property2);
```

That will work on .NET >= 3.5. Benefit of this option is ability to work with any enumerable source (i.e. if you'll change list to ICollection, or some other enumerable type).

Comment: what if I have to compare another condition along with the one inside list, Ex List<MyClass>().All(m => m.StringProp.Contains("ss") && (m.IsValid == true && somelclvrblval ==1))? will this work?

Comment: @AdarshK yes, it will work. You just should pass predicate which returns boolean value after testing list item. Side note - if condition is pretty complex, then you can consider to use [Specification](http://martinfowler.com/apsupp/spec.pdf)

Comment: Not sure I got you - 'pass predicate which returns boolean value after testing list item'

Comment: @AdarshK predicate is a delegate `Func<T, bool>` - i.e. any method which accepts T (item from list in this case) and returns boolean. It can be anonymous method like above, or it can be named method like `private bool IsValid(ObjectA a) { return a.property2; }` you can pass this method `list.TrueForAll(IsValid)`

Answer (score 3):

if you want to make sure if all elements of a particular collection satisfy a condition you can use All method in Linq, like this:

```
 new List<MyClass>().All(m => m.StringProp.Contains("ss") && m.IsValid == true)
```

Comment: this would return a bool true or false?

Answer (score 0):

Use LINQ:

```
List<ObjectA> list;

//Check for string
if (list.Any(a => a.property1.Contains("xyz")))
{

}

// Check for true
if (list.Any(a => a.property2 ?? false))
{

}
```

If you need to get the objects that satisfies your conditions, use list.Where(...)

Answer (score 0):

There are several possible checks and results you can easily get.

```
void Main()
{       //ignore Dump() method
    var list = new List<ObjectA>() 
    {
        new ObjectA("name1", true),
        new ObjectA("name2", true),
        new ObjectA("name3", null),
        new ObjectA("name4", false),
        new ObjectA("name5", null),
        new ObjectA("name6", false),
        new ObjectA("name7", true)
    };
    //check if all Items are valid
var allItems = list.All(m => m.Name.Contains("ss") && m.valid == true); // false
    //only get valid items (name contains name AND true)
var validItems = list.Where (l => l.Name.Contains("name") && l.valid == true).Dump();
    //get all items which are invalid
var nonvalidItems = list.Where(l =>!(l.Name.Contains("name")) || l.valid != true).Dump();
```

}

```
public class ObjectA
{
  public ObjectA(string name, bool? _val)
  {
    this.Name = name;
    if(_val.HasValue)
      this.valid = _val;
  }
 public string Name { get; set; }
 public bool? valid { get; set; }
}
```